# wp_mail doesn't send the attachment in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, email

I have this code and it should work, the email is sent but without the attachment.

```
$attachments = THEME_DIR . '/resources/img/emails/cropped.png';

$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';

wp_mail( 'test@example.org', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments );
```

Comment: Your code works good for me, so check if the attachment actually exists - `var_dump( file_exists( $attachments ) )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out that you just need to use ABSPATH.

```
$attachments = [
    ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/themename/resources/img/emails/cropped.png',
    ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/themename/resources/img/emails/facebook.png'
];

// Send the email and the invoice as an attachment.
wp_mail( 'test@email.com', 'New Invoice', 'Message body sent with attachment.', $headers, $attachments );
```

You can set up also these or just include them in $headers:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', function ( $content_type ) {
    return 'text/html';
} );

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'yoursite_wp_mail_from' );
function yoursite_wp_mail_from( $content_type ) {
    return 'contact@yoursite.ca';
}

add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'yoursite_wp_mail_from_name' );
function yoursite_wp_mail_from_name( $name ) {
    return 'Your Site Inc.';
}
```